# Preg replace match all words / complete sentences

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use a function to replace some keywords in a search form.

```
function replace_search($input, $output, $string)
{

$string = preg_replace("/\b$input\b/i", "$output", $string);

return $string;
}
```

**Keyword example 1:**

```
$input = 'levelers';
$output = 'roller leveller';
$search = replace_search($input, $output, $search);
```

**Keyword example 2:**

```
$input1 = 'roller levelers machine';
$output1 = 'roller leveller';
$search = replace_search($input1, $output1, $search);
```

Problem: The function doestn match the whole string. When the search-phrase is:

*roller levelers machine*

Result is:

*roller roller leveller machine*

because the Keyword example 1 match the word levelers. But this is wrong.

Result has to be only "roller leveller".

thanks

Comment: Your description is somewhat hard to understand. What is it supposed to do exactly? What do you want as output?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you can use a if(preg_match(blabla)){bla}else if(preg_match(bla2bla2)){} and so on. This way it will only match once. And if you keep the longest match first and shortest last maybe it could work.